# Implementation of regularized competing risk models with random effects

Tags: survival, regularization, software, competing-risks

Are there any existing software implementations of regularized competing risk cox models with that also allow for random effects (i.e., competing risk frailty models)? That is, models that allow for penalizing fixed effect slopes in the context of a mixed-effects competing risk Cox model? In my use case, the goal is identifying predictors of cause-specific mortality hazard in data with observations nested within families.

My search of the [R survival analysis task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Survival.html) has identified close candidates, but nothing that meets all of the above criteria. For example, [crrp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/crrp/index.html) has a variety of regularization schemes (LASSO, SCAD, etc...) implemented for competing risks models *without* varying intercepts/slopes.

Comment: I would look into the coxme package, it is an extension of the survival package in R and allows for random effects. I just tested to see if you can do comp risk models with random effects, and you can. However, I am not sure if the package was validated for competing risk- it is just programmatically possible.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the suggestion--I'm actually already using `coxme`, it's a great package but doesn't implement regularization methods for fixed effect coefficients